# Is encapsulation of CSS and JS necessary for a Google Chrome extention that overrides the `new tab` page?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am doing a Chrome Extention that overrides the page that appears when the user opens a new tab or window.

I read the [general guidelines](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/override) but I still wonder - should I encapsulate of my CSS and JS?

I don't see any reason to encapsulate them, my Chrome Extention overrides a separate page and doesn't load on top of other websites. Therefore, I think I am safe without any encapsulation, right?

Comment: The same could be said for popup and background pages, which do require encapsulation.  But why not just try it real quick and see what happens?  (But also, encapsulation is a "best practice" (tm).  Why don't you want to use it?)

Comment: Yes, I did a test and everything looks and sounds okay. I was wondering if there are any pitfalls. I am doing some basic encapsulation of course, but for example I do also some global resets, like using `reset.css` that modified the generic HTML elements for example.

Comment: In your extension pages there's only the default user-agent CSS besides your own.

Comment: Thank you, @wOxxOm , that's what I thought too. I wanted to double check.